# Number of significant digits using numpy can be increased?

Tags: numpy

When I decrease the value of a coefficient in my code something stops working. Can I have a division by zero without an error message? Can this be solved by increasing the number of significant digits?
How can I increase the number of significant digits in numpy? Thank you

Comment: Numpy division warns on division by zero and float overflow, `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide` `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in divide`. Of course the overflow could be happening in a different function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy does not support arbitrary precision. [see here](http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/ticket/8054). The scalar types they have [are these](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in).

Consider using [fractions module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) or other library w arbitrary precision...